# TFS team room does not show git push events

Tags: tfs

We have an on-premise TFS 2013 (updated from 2010) but in the team room of a Git project appear no commit / push event messages.

It works with TFSSC projects (check-ins) or Visual Studio Online (both) so I think, that I 'managed the events' correctly. Email alerts are sent fine.
(I'm not sure whether it is related. When I change the push alert email template to plain text, the email contains only an error message

> The XSL style sheet for event type GitPushEvent could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Can you find this xsl in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033\GitPushEvent.xsl ?

Comment: Yes, the file is there (12 KB).